# Is there a way to deserialize CSV to object, mapping by varied column names?

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to deserialize CSVs to objects, mapping by varied column names, as illustrated by the following examples:

**Input 1**
Id;Name;Document
1;Matheus;555777
2;Clarice;567890

**Input 2**
"Id_Person";"First_Name";"Phone"
3;"John";"999-9999"

```
public class People
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Doc { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the column names change by file, and a column can even be missing.

I would like to map "Id" and "Id_Person" to the PersonId property, and so on.

How to do it?

Comment: Read the columns and if possible map to the right property. After that, you can just initialize properties with mapped columns.

Comment: Do you know all the file format variations or will they be unpredictable?

Comment: Unpredictable. And I would prefer, if possible, to not write my own deserializer and have to deal with the hassle of all the variations and peculiarities of CSV files.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't have much confidence in any solution.

Comment: Upredictable => if you don't have a pattern matching you can't tell to the deserializer or any one else than how to deserialize.

Comment: We plan to add a good number of variations, based on files submitted by users (and we already have some documented), but it's indeed impossible to map everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found something that solved my problem: [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Setting up:

```
public sealed class PessoaCSVMap : ClassMap<Pessoas>
{
    public PessoaCSVMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.NomeCompleto).Name("Nome", "Name");
        Map(m => m.Documento).Name("Documento", "Doc", "CPF");
        Map(m => m.Email1).Name("Email", "Email1", "E-mail", "E-mail1");
        Map(m => m.PessoaId).Ignore();
    }
}
```

Using:

```
const string CSV = "Nome;Email;bleu\nMatheus;matheus.lacerda@email.com.br;blau\nClarice;null;null";
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StringReader(CSV));
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<PessoaCSVMap>();
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
List<Pessoas> pessoas = csv.GetRecords<Pessoas>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already can read a specific CSV Line, this one manages to give a lot of flexibility with some reflection and generics . Not a works for all method, but it's easy to adapt it for different cases :

```
    public IEnumerable<T> ProccessCSV<T>(StreamReader document, char divider) 
        where T : class, new()
    {
        string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] usedHeaders = currentLine.Split(divider);

        while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var fields = currentLine.Split(divider);
            var result = new T();
            for (var i = 0; i < usedHeaders.Length; i++)
                {
                    var value = fields[i];
                    var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties()[i];
                    result.GetType()
                            .GetProperty(propInfo.Name)
                            .SetValue(result, value);
                }
            yield return result;
        }
    }
```

Hope this works as a backbone to a possible solution.

For the first case, you'll need to use a separator ';' and a class like :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Document { get; set; }
}
```

Based on : https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/microsoft-net/building-a-generic-csv-writer-reader-using-reflection